# Como Acumular strings numa única variável?

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Estou tentando resgatar os nomes de anexos numa única variável para depois imprimi-los todos juntos. Reparem que já envio cada arquivo para a pasta upload. Entao este nao é o caso. Quero mesmo apenas resgatar os nomes desses anexos, mais nada. Como fazer isto? Estes anexos veem de um imput file multiple então num loop envio todos os arquivos para a pasta upload com sucesso. Mas quero aproveitar o loop para o resgate do nome.

```
<?php  

   $arquivo = isset($_FILES['foto']) ? $_FILES['foto'] : FALSE;

   for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++){

       $destino = $diretorio."/" . date("d.m.Y-H.i.s"). $arquivo['name'][$k];

       $acumulaNome = ; // Como ficaria esta variavel que acumula os nomes apenas?

       if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino)) {echo "Sucesso"; }

       else {echo "erro";}
    }   

?>
```

Comment: `$acumulaNome .= $arquivo['name'][$k] ."\r\n";` - O `"\r\n"` é a quebra de linha, pode trocar por `"<br>"` ou `"<br>\n"` se for exibir em página web. Dependendo da aplicação, pode usar só `"\n"` que já resolve. Provavelmente o `implode` seja o caminho mais adequado, como dito pelo Omine.

Comment: Estava ate agora a tentar resolver meu problema com inicio nesta variavel $acumulaNome e vi seu comentario.  Simplesmente a melhor resposta e totalmente funcional, fiz os teste e ja listo os nomes, mudo o nome (coisa q nao conseguia nas outras respostas) recebo o e-mail com a lista de todos os nomes, bastando enviar a variavel. Fabuloso. Muito obrigado, Se quiser fazer a pergunta marco rua resposta

Comment: Golx pode deixar como está, a resposta do @DanielOmine está boa. O `implode(', ', $arquivo['name']);` daria na mesma, só que vc troca a ',' pelo que eu comentei acima. `"\r"`, ou mesmo `"<br>\r"`. Exemplo: DEPOIS DO LOOP, não dentro, você põe assim: `$acumulanome = implode( "<br>\n", $arquivo['name'] );`

Comment: Ok. Obrigado, se eu fiz uma boa pergunta, marca por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Se quer uma sugestão**,

remova essa variável, pois é inútil.

```
$acumulaNome = ;
```

Os nomes dos arquivos já estão na variável `$arquivo['name']`.

Então para imprimir esses nomes bastaria fazer algo assim

```
echo implode(', ', $arquivo['name']);
```

Imprimirá os nomes dos arquivos separados por vírgula.

**Caso queira continuar da forma como está**, esqueça o implode() e faça somente isso

```
$acumulaNome .= $arquivo['name'].', ';
```

Para imprimir, faça `echo rtrim($acumulaNome, ', ');`

O `rtrim()` é para remover a vírgula que fica sobrando no final.

Comment: join é depreciado no PHP. use `explode` ao invés.

Comment: Correção: Com a loucura de ficar trocando as coisas do php,  agora ela é uma `alias` para `implode` (que torna desencorajante, pois os alias no php são desencorajados). Mas antigamente ela era desencorajada e lançava um deprecated :(

Comment: Daniel, devem ter atualizado ou então eu me confundi com o `split`. Mas qualquer função no php que seja alias, a documentação **geralmente** costuma desencorajar (por poder ser removida nas versões futuras). Mas não é o tema da pergunta, então deixa pra lá ;)

Comment: @DanielOmine, obrigado pelas respostas mas nao consegui sucesso. Consigo realmente dar echo com implode(', ', $arquivo['name']); estavam la todos os nomes, mas devo estar fazendo  alguma coisa errada, estou enviando o implode no corpo de um email por php mailler e no email da chega a lista. como posso enviar por email estes nomes na $arquivo[nome]

Comment: Ok, como devo fazer esta pergunta? é que posso ser negativado a becas...Como enviar por phpmailler uma variavel com strings acumuladas?

Comment: apenas entenda que a dúvida subsequente torna-se uma dúvida secundária e sequer foi descrita na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

No PHP existe duas alterativas.

Você pode acumular com um `array`.

Exemplo:

```
$acumula = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $acumula[] = $i;
}
```

Resultado:

```
[
     1,
     2,
     3,
     4,
     5,
     6,
     7,
     8,
     9,
]
```

Ou com uma concatenando uma `string`.

```
$acumula = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $acumula .= $i;
}
```

Resultado:

```
"123456789"
```

Creio que no seu caso, o mais viável seria combinar o agrupamento por `array`, usando `implode` posteriormente:

```
$arquivo = isset($_FILES['foto']) ? $_FILES['foto'] : FALSE;

$acumulaNome = [];

for ($k = 0; $k < count($arquivo['name']); $k++){

    $destino = $diretorio."/" . date("d.m.Y-H.i.s"). $arquivo['name'][$k];

    $acumulaNome[] = $arquivo['name'][$k]; // Como ficaria esta variavel que acumula os nomes apenas?

    if (move_uploaded_file($arquivo['tmp_name'][$k], $destino)) {

        echo "Sucesso"; 
    } else {
        echo "erro"; 
    }
} 


echo implode(', ', $acumulaNome);
```

Comment: Esta opção array era o que eu queria que funcionasse pra mim mas nem o echo implode(', ', $acumulaNome);  imprime, e estou obtendo um "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/megah126/public_html/classya/Cadasto/cadasto.php on line 3.